# Error: "kernel.asm:2: error: parser: instruction expected"

Tags: assembly, kernel, nasm

I'm working on a project where I'm trying to assemble and link a bootloader, kernel, and UI code using NASM, GCC, and LD. However, I'm encountering an error during the assembly process of the kernel.asm file. The specific error message I'm getting is:

```
kernel.asm:2: error: parser: instruction expected
```

I have double-checked the code and made sure it follows the correct assembly syntax, but I'm still unable to resolve the issue. I'm relatively new to assembly language programming, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Code Snippet:

```
[BITS 16]
ORG 0x8000

section kernel

extern ui_main   ; Declare the entry point of the UI code

start:
    mov ax, 0x07C0  ; Set up segment registers
    mov ds, ax
    mov es, ax

    call clearScreen
    call ui_main

    jmp $

clearScreen:
    mov ah, 0x00    ; Video BIOS - Set video mode
    mov al, 0x03    ; Mode 3 (Text mode: 80x25, 16 colors)
    int 0x10        ; Video interrupt
    ret

times 510 - ($ - $$) db 0
dw 0xAA55         ; Boot signature
```

I would greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue. Thank you in advance for your help!

Steps I've taken:

Verified the syntax of the assembly code.
Made sure the code follows the correct assembly language syntax.
Double-checked for any typographical errors or missing characters.
Ensured that the NASM version is compatible with the code.
Expected Output:
I expect the code to assemble successfully without any errors.

Edit im not sure how to say answered but i got it working because of Jester's `PS: 0x8000 doesn't seem correct anyway. Since you set ds to 0x07C0 the org should be zero which is the default.`

Comment: What command did you use? I assume something like `nasm -f elf32` ... but `org` is not supported for ELF, so remove that and use the linker.

Comment: PS: `0x8000` doesn't seem correct anyway. Since you set `ds` to `0x07C0` the `org` should be zero which is the default.

Comment: That's an MBR boot sector.  Build it with `nasm -fbin`, not into an ELF object file.  The `call ui_main` can't work if you use this as a bootloader, because only this first 512 bytes will get loaded, not any later sectors unless you do those manually.  But you don't.

Comment: yeah i used -f and i wouldent need to set the org then? And im using a c ui thing